# error: conflicting types for 'SpimodFlashWrite'

Tags: c, microblaze

i am getting error in function when i call this function to another function may be second argument int u16 address i am passing wrong

```
int SpimodFlashWrite(XSpi *SpiPtr, u16 Address, u16 ByteCount)
{
u16 Index;

/*
 * Setup the write command with the specified address, and data to be
 * written to the flash.
 */
WriteBuffer[MOD_COMMAND_OFFSET]       = MOD_COMMAND_WRITE;
WriteBuffer[MOD_ADDRESS_BYTE1_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 16);
WriteBuffer[MOD_ADDRESS_BYTE2_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address >> 8);
WriteBuffer[MOD_ADDRESS_BYTE3_OFFSET] = (u8) (Address);

/*
 * Prepare the write buffer. Fill in the data that is to be written into
 * the Flash.
 */
for(Index = 4; Index < (ByteCount + MOD_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES);Index++)
{
    WriteBuffer[Index] = (u8)(MOD_TEST_BYTE + Index);
}

/*
 * Send the write command, address, and data to the Flash.
 * No receive buffer is specified since there is nothing to receive.
 */
TransferInProgress = TRUE;
XSpi_Transfer(SpiPtr, WriteBuffer, NULL,
        ByteCount + MOD_READ_WRITE_EXTRA_BYTES)
                        ;

/*
 * Wait till the Transfer is complete and check if there are any errors
 * in the transaction.
 */
while (TransferInProgress);
if(ErrorCount != 0) {
    ErrorCount = 0;
    return XST_FAILURE;
}

return XST_SUCCESS;
```

}

if i am using this function like this

```
 `int express_configure( void )
  {

 int Status;
 unsigned char b[3];
  b[0] = 0xD4;
 b[1]=29;b[2]=0x80;
 Status = SpimodFlashWrite(&Spi, b, 3);
```

`

error: conflicting types for 'SpimodFlashWrite'

Thanks

Comment: Is the `SpimodFlashWrite` function declared in a header file? Do you include the header file? How do you declare the function in the header file?

Comment: hello` int SpimodFlashWrite(XSpi *SpiPtr, u32 Address, u16 ByteCount);`
i declare like this in header

Comment: Yes then you have a conflicting type. What is the type of the argument `Address`? And to make matters worse, you're calling it incorrectly as well (assuming that both `u32` and `u16` as unsigned integer types).

Comment: what is this warning  `warning: passing argument 2 of 'SpimodFlashWrite' makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default] `??

Comment: It's exactly what it sounds like. You say that the argument to the function is an integer value. But you pass a pointer. Perhaps you should take a few steps back, get a book (any book really) and learn about arrays, pointers, and how arrays decays to pointers.